# Cannot use a Laravel object in an if statement

Tags: php, laravel

I have this weird error:

I have this if:

```
if($item->condition && $item->variable)
{
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Which gives me this error:

> ErrorException in Controller.php line 9001: Trying to
>   get property of non-object

I have used dd() to debug both variables:

```
dd($item)->condition

if($item->condition && $item->variable)
{
//do something
}
```

Which returns 0 (as expected).

```
dd($item->variable)

if($item->condition && $item->variable)
{
//do something
}
```

Which returns null (also as expected). So $item is an object which contains the variable condition with 0 and the variable variable with null. However I still get this error. If I change `$item->variable` in the database to "foobar", `dd($item->variable)` will actually contain "foobar".

How come I cannot use the if here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like `$item` isn't an `Object`, or is `null`. Can you include the code that returns `$item`? Is it an `Eloquent` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
if(!empty($item->condition) && !empty($item->variable))
```

it will check if variable isset and check for null value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `property_exists` with a check for `$item` to ensure that item exists.

```
if(!isnull($item) && property_exists($item, 'condition') && property_exists($item, 'variable'))
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **isset()** function,

```
if(isset($item->condition) && isset($item->variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you show how you have passed the $item. Try using the code in view

```
 @foreach($item as $i)
if($i->condition && $i->variable)
{
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
@endforeach
```